# IE button click with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, button

Can't get the "GO" button to click via VBA on this site: https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/BondDetail.jsp?ticker=C631551&symbol=RDS4242315

Will eventually want to loop code. Should be simple...just can't get this one.

```
Sub Macro1()
 'we define the essential variables
Dim ie As Object
Dim acct
Dim button

   Set Rng = Range("B4:B4")

Set Row = Range(Rng.Offset(1, 0), Rng.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown))

For Each Row In Rng

   'add the "Microsoft Internet Controls" reference in your VBA Project indirectly
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate ("https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/BondDetail.jsp?ticker=C631551&symbol=RDS4242315")
    While ie.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
    Set Cusip = .document.getElementById("ms-finra-autocomplete-box") 'id of the username control (HTML Control)
        Cusip.Value = Range("B" & Row.Row).Value



      ie.document.getElementsByTagName("submit").Click



End With

Next Row
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The tag name of your button is not "submit" but "INPUT" ... "submit" is the type.

But watch out, there are more INPUT elements, so your getElementsBy... will return a collection and you need to further dig to find the correct one, e.g. by checking a significant attribute.

Example

```
' ...

Set ECol = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
For Each IFld In ECol
    If IFld.getAttribute("class") = "button_blue autocomplete-go" Then
        IFld.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next IFld

' ...
```